How to automatically sort rows in a table alphabetically?
I am dealing with this table shown below.
> \begin{longtable}{p{5cm}p{5cm}p{5cm}}
>         \toprule
>         Simbol & Definicija & SI jedinica \\
>         \midrule\endhead % Add Latin symbols alphabetically here:
>         $S$ & entropija & [\SI{}{J.K^{-1}}] \\
>         $q$ & toplina & [\SI{}{J}] \\
>         $T$ & termodinamička temperatura & [\SI{}{K}] \\
>         $U$ & unutarnja energija & [\SI{}{J}] \\
>         $w$ & rad & [\SI{}{J}] \\
>         $p$ & tlak & [\SI{}{Pa}] \\
>         $V$ & volumen & [\SI{}{m^3}] \\
>         $A$ & Helmholtzova energija & [\SI{}{J}] \\
>         $H$ & entalpija & [\SI{}{J}] \\
>         $G$ & Gibbsova energija & [\SI{}{J}] \\
>         ... \\
>         \bottomrule
>     \end{longtable}

I would like to have the rows sorted alphabetically with each new entry in the table. I've already tried the other codes that were posted here, but it didn't work (kept getting errors). Any help is appreciated! :)

use a dedicated package like glossaries or acro that can sort entries.

You can sort the lines by storing them first in memory, sorting them, and then typesetting the table, like Order table by row alphabetically, or you can keep the rows in a csv file (or write it from the tex file by a filecontents environment) and then use a package like datatool to read the csv file, sort it, and typeset it as a table, like How can I sort a list numerically?.

Consider adding your symbols into a database using tools from datatool. The following example shows your use case with a custom macro to enter content into a database, sort it, and then use that sorted database to construct a table (automatically with \DTLdisplaydb or manually with \DTLforeach).

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\addsymbol}{m m m}{%
  % \addsymbol{<symbol>}{<definition>}{<notation>}
  \DTLifdbexists{symboldef}{}{\DTLnewdb{symboldef}}% Create symboldef database if needed
  \DTLnewrow{symboldef}% Add new entry
  \DTLnewdbentry{symboldef}{symbol}{#1}% Add symbol
  \DTLnewdbentry{symboldef}{definition}{#2}% Add definition
  \DTLnewdbentry{symboldef}{notation}{#3}% Add notation
}

\begin{document}

% Add symbol entries
\addsymbol{S}{entropija}{\SI{}{J.K^{-1}}}
\addsymbol{q}{toplina}{\SI{}{J}}
\addsymbol{T}{termodinamička temperatura}{\SI{}{K}}
\addsymbol{U}{unutarnja energija}{\SI{}{J}}
\addsymbol{w}{rad}{\SI{}{J}}
\addsymbol{p}{tlak}{\SI{}{Pa}}
\addsymbol{V}{volumen}{\SI{}{m^3}}
\addsymbol{A}{Helmholtzova energija}{\SI{}{J}}
\addsymbol{H}{entalpija}{\SI{}{J}}
\addsymbol{G}{Gibbsova energija}{\SI{}{J}}

% Display database
\DTLdisplaydb{symboldef}

% Sort database based on symbol
\dtlsort{symbol}{symboldef}{\dtlwordindexcompare}

% Display database
\DTLdisplaydb{symboldef}

\clearpage

\begin{longtable}{ c p{5cm} c }
  \toprule
  Simbol & Definicija & SI jedinica \\
  \midrule\endhead % Add Latin symbols alphabetically here:
  \DTLforeach{symboldef}{%
    \Symbol=symbol,
    \Definition=definition,
    \Notation=notation}{%
    \DTLiffirstrow{}{\\}% Start a new row
    $\Symbol$ & \Definition & \Notation} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}


Sort the lines in your editor, tex does not hold the table in memory, the first few rows may already have been typeset and written to the pdf file before the later lines have even been read from the source file.

A useful way I have found to do this: You can use either Excel, or OpenOffice equivalent, sort it, and then copy the table and paste it in https://www.tablesgenerator.com/ - It gives you the output in the format you want it for LaTeX and allows for toprule, midrule and all the other commands OP (@crvenikupus) wanted to use
